# I changed my SMTP config from gmail to another. Mail HTML was broken

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I changed the SMTP config to another server from gmail SMTP. In gmail SMTP it works fine. When I changed the SMTP, mail content HTML was broken. Please check the below screenshot.[image]. Anybody know what happened. I just changed the SMTP. Any encoding issues?

Comment: Why everyone giving me down vote? Any mistake in my question?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution. It was the issue of phpmailer. Please check the [link.](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/563) I downgraded my phpmailer version to fix this issue.